# Android making scale (ruler) on screen

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable, android-graphics

In my application I want to create a ruler to measure length. I have gone through some ruler application in google store. I want to achieve somewhat as shown in the picture.

So my question is how do I draw this marking as per users mobile screen configuration. Is it using using some drawable image or some drawing on canvas.

I am new to android development. Also that the ruler when dragged downward marking and numbering move. So how to achieve[image] that thing.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of things that requires programmatical access to the data is mostly done using 'drawing to the canvas', which in this case is a window spawned by a service.

You should look into overlay activity implementations such as [bubbles for android](https://github.com/txusballesteros/bubbles-for-android), which lets you peek into the way this is usually achieved, which is by creating a service that adds a window to the system that draws this, from there you can get the screen details, width and height to draw the ruler with.

Inside the spawned window you can add your own subclass of a view that implements the [onDraw](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) method in such a way that the ruler is drawn on the canvas.

Comment: I know how to draw window on top of other app, but question is how to draw these markings in ruler. Is it using canvas and android.graphics or something else?

Comment: You can add a custom view into the window you've spawned that knows how to draw the ruler, that's how I would do it. View has onDraw method that passes canvas as parameter, which will let you draw on it.